# get first and last element from sqlite database

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by, union, sql-limit

Following example here -> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-get-the-first-and-last-record-of-the-table-in-mysql

To get first and last element of database we can use UNION.
I have a table called location with three queries.

[image]

And I would like to get rows with id 1 and in this case 3 (db will be much larger)
So I tried

```
(select * from location order by id ASC LIMIT 1)
UNION
(select * from location order by id DESC LIMIT 1);
```

But It doesn't work in my example. Does sqlite allow to use UNION operation?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does support `UNION` but does not like the queries inside the parentheses.

Use each of your queries as a subquery:

```
select * from (select * from location order by id ASC LIMIT 1)
UNION
select * from (select * from location order by id DESC LIMIT 1);
```